# Cannot remove time series seasonality

Tags: time-series, stat, advanced-custom-fields

I am currently working on fit a SARIMA model to my dataset. When I explore the acf of the dataset, there is seasonality which shows slow linearly decay at lag 24, 48, 72...(houly data). Then following standard procedure, I did differencing at lag 24 to remove the seasonality. However, no matter how many times I have tried (3 or 4 time differencing at lag 24), acf still shows seasonality at lag 24 and outside the bound. Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: This question is better suited for Cross Validated. Also, it'd be helpful to provide example data.

Comment: Can you post the data? It would be easier to see what you get. You can for example post the data in Comma Separated Value format (with seasons by rows to save space).